# How to not allow users to see members other than their own downline?

Tags: php, laravel

I am creating an MLM like web application.
I have a page in which I need to show the members in a hierarchy below the logged in user. 4 children are shown on this page along with 4 grandchildren from each children. When the user clicks on one of the grandchildren, the great grandchildren from that grandchildren are shown.

Currently, I am creating a hyperlink like `http://localhost:8000/downline/8866220099` but in this way, a user can manually make a URL by appending any other userId (in this case 8866220099) and view that user's children/grandchildren.

I want to restrict a user A from viewing user B's grandchildren. How do I accomplish that ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use an API key to verify the identity of the user.

Comment: Could you please explain me the working of the API keys in my case. I looked upon API keys but didn't find it similar to my case.

Comment: @Vivek you give the user a secret key, and store this key on your server as well. This key is supplied as a parameter when making the request to the downline/12345?key=secretSomething. Only requests where the user who the key belongs to has access should be served.

Comment: But then, if only the key has to be added in the uri, Any user can do that manually. Like user A can see user B's children by downline/12345?key=a1b2c3d4 (consider 12345 as B's child)

Comment: >>Only requests where the user who the key belongs to has access should be served.

You should check serverside that the owner of that key has permission to view whatever they are trying to view.

Comment: The API key would help me in preventing unauthorised access. But in this case, there would be thousands of children and grandchildren and great grandchildren all together. How do I prevent a parent from viewing another parent's downline hierarchy ?